# mouse lagging if windbg attach to a process which hook global mouse event

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg

While debugging my c# application which hook global mouse event, I found after attach to my application using windbg, the mouse's response is very slow. After comment out the hook, the lagging is gone.

I am using a library called globalmousekeyhook. To reproduce the issue, download source code from [globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook), then compile the solution, set FormsExample as startup project & run it. Then using windbg attach demo.exe

If comment out all the code inside Subscribe(), the lagging issue is gone.

```
    private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        // Note: for the application hook, use the Hook.AppEvents() instead
        m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();

        m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt += GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
        m_GlobalHook.KeyPress += GlobalHookKeyPress;
    }
```

I've had the same problem when debugging some other applications. Does windbg has any solution for this issue?

Windbg version:
Windbg preview
Debugger client version: 1.0.2007.06001
Debugger engine version: 10.0.20153.1000

Windbg 10.0.19041 in window 10 SDK has the same issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I suspect the application I am trying to debug uses a global mouse hook as well. But I was suspecting it already for other reasons and am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @AridTag Not yet. I didn't find any solution for it :(

Comment: for what it's worth, in my case I was able to locate the instructions in the target assembly that were creating the mouse hook and disable it. Thus stopping my mouse from becoming unusable.

Comment: @AridTag Thanks!